# How do I add a new Razor Page Template to Visual Studio in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: templates, razor, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

I've got the Templates folder in my project hierarchy, and I've been modifying those pretty heavily to speed up my scaffolding workflow.

However, some of the objects in my database must persist forever.  So, since they can't be deleted, they have a boolean activation state.

As such, I'd like to add two new actions to the CRUD workflow, Deactivate and Reactivate.  I added the relevant templates to the Project\Templates\RazorPageGenerator folder, but when I click to add a new Razor Page, it still only shows the standard CRUD options.

I'm not sure where I need to register the new templates for them to be usable in the scaffolding operations...?

Comment: Nobody on the internet seems to have the answer for this. Seems like such a simple thing, too.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I normally do and works all the time:

- Right click the folder => Select Add > New File => Select Razor Page and modify the "Name" section to match my controller method name.

If it doesn't work for you, how about creating files "Deactivate.cshtml" and "Reactivate.cshtml" using normal means (Finder in MacOS, Window Explorer in Windows, or command prompt), copy them to your Project\Templates\RazorPageGenerator folder, and add them to your project by right click the folder in VS2017 => Select Add > Add Files from Folder

Comment: So, the top part is just how to create a Razor page.  That's not helpful.  I know how to create Razor Pages.

The bottom part, I've already done, as I explained in the question.

The question is: how to get those templates in the dropdown when creating a new Razor Page.

Answer (score -1):

In .csprog change Project Sdk From Microsoft.NET.Sdk To Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).